# Eclipse delete Plugins from Folder

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

So I was using **Eclipse 2022-06** Version and everything was working fine.

I then wanted to install **JBoss Tools** Plugins (Eclipse Marketplace) which also looked good. After the Installation  Eclipse asked to restart, which I did.

Now my Eclipse cant be opened again. Its gets stuck on load screen and Java Runtime takes 100% CPU. Is there a way to delete the last Plugins that were installed? If yes then from what folders and how do I make sure to only delete that part?

I am trying to use the newest Version but my old setup had some packages and preferences that I dont want to lose..

~ Faded

Edit: When I am trying to take a existing Installation:

[image: eclipse]

(also tried with the checkbox enabled)

[image: folder]

Comment: Preferences are stored in the workspace and you can install things from an existing Eclipse installation into your new installation (via _File > Import...: Install > From Existing Installation). You can also try from [the command line to revert/uninstall installed features](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html).

Comment: @howlger Could you tell me what I have to pick when trying to install from Existing Installation? I cant wrap my head around what folder/file to pick.

Comment: The installation folder/directory of the existing (old) Eclipse installation.

Comment: In case you used the Eclipse Installer, try `<your user directory>\.p2\pool`.

Comment: I used Eclipse Installer, I navigated to the Folder but when I use "pool" as the folder - again no files where found..

Comment: Did you uncheck _Hide items that already installed_?

Comment: Where can I uncheck this Option? Only Checkbox I see is "Include entries not found in repositories"

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Use _Help > Install New Software..._, work with `file://C:\<your user directory>\.p2\pool` and uncheck _Group items by category_ (and maybe also _Hide items that are already installed_). If possible, install it from the official update site to get updates.

Comment: Okay I found some packages now that I can probably install. There is multiple packages for the same dependencie - is it safe to just select all and hit install? Or would it be better to only take the newest versions. For example: I have 4 Versions of DevStyles.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. It would be better not to have DevStyle and other plugins from the same vendor at all since they try to cheat the Eclipse license via load-time weaving which can cause issues and slow down Eclipse. For other plugins, better use the newest version.

Comment: @howlger Now my "new" Eclipse is not starting up :D But anyways thanks because I learned some things today. I think Im gonna reinstall everything from scratch again.

Comment: That doesn't sound good and shouldn't happen. Can you figure out which plugin is causing it?

Comment: Honestly openenig the Log File it seems like everything failed :D Java Fx and JasperSoft is defo listed but I feel like every Package is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not simple, the p2 Director application can handle it. It's [Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) (somewhat).

Another alternative is to try creating a brand-new workspace; occasionally, it's the workspace rather than the plug-in itself that causes an issue.

The only other choice is to just remove your Eclipse installation (but keep your workspace) and then re-extract a fresh copy. It's simple to perform because Eclipse's "installation" is simply a zip/tar extraction. All third-party plugins that you already have and want to keep would need to be re-installed.